# Add Avatar image to only one page with pelican-bootstrap3

Tags: jinja2, pelican

Here is my unfinished site that I have made with [pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/index.html) using the [pelican-bootstrap3](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes/tree/master/pelican-bootstrap3) template: http://snoek.ddns.net/~oliver/mysite/

In the [pelican-bootstrap3](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes/tree/master/pelican-bootstrap3) README, it says can use the AVATAR variable in the `pelicanconf.py` file to point to an image. I've done this but now the picture of me is on every page, which is a little ridiculous. I would like it only on my "About" page.

In [pelican-themes/pelican-bootstrap3/templates/includes](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes/tree/master/pelican-bootstrap3/templates/includes) I found an `aboutme.html` file with the following in it:

```
<div id="aboutme">
    {% if AVATAR %}
        <p>
            <img width="100%" class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ AVATAR }}"/>
        </p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if ABOUT_ME %}
    <p>
      <strong>{{ _('About') }} {{ AUTHOR }}</strong><br/>
        {{ ABOUT_ME }}
    </p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Maybe it is this file that could be edited to specify that the avatar should only show on the "About" page? But I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
{% if AVATAR %}
```

To

```
{% if page and page.title == 'About' and (ABOUT_ME or AVATAR) %}
```